Что такое f-строки в Питоне?
Что такое f-строки в python и как их использовать?

f-строки - это особые форматируемые строки, появившиеся в версии python 3.6
Пример использования без f-строк:
name = "Макс"
age = 16
print("Привет, я ", name, ". Мне ", age, "лет.")

# Вывод: Привет, я Макс. Мне 16 лет.

Пример использования с f-строками:
name = "Макс"
age = 16
print(f"Привет, я {name}. Мне {age} лет.")
#Вывод: Привет, я Макс. Мне 16 лет.


В чем смысл? До туториала явно не дотягивает, решение конкретной проблемы не затрагивает.

не стоит делать подобные кульбиты с сам-себе-ответами на элементарные вопросы. я так понимаю, это у же не первый "вопрос". Вы себе хотите просто очки заработать?

Нормальный самоответ. Можете лучше - пожалуйста добавьте )

@strawdog нет, не из-за этого

@Kromster могу лучше. но не буду - пусть читают учебник.

@Grant а зачем тогда засорять RuSO подобной ерундой?

@strawdog то что вы многое знаете это отлично, но это не значит, что остальные тоже это знают. Можно посмотреть топ 1000 вопросов на SO - это все "тривиальщина".

"Остальные" и не будут ничего знать, если из-за каждой ерунды будут писать вопросы здесь, ничуть не экономя свое время и тратя чужое.
